# How to send silent notification to ioS and Android using Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub, silentpush

I am trying to test silent notifications using Azure Notification Hub. I have not used it before so I wanted to know if we can do it. If yes, then what should be the payload. Currently, when I click on "Test Send" it opens a payload and I wanted to know what should be the payload if we want a silent notification where we just want to activate the app but not actually send a notification.

Current Payload as per Azure

```
{
    "notification":{
        "title":"Notification Hub Test Notification",
        "body":"This is a sample notification delivered by Azure Notification Hubs."
    },
    "data":{
        "property1":"value1",
        "property2":42
    }
}
```

What needs to be changed here in the payload

Answer (score 2):

Removing the "notification" portion of this payload will make this a silent notification.

Comment: Will it work for both android and ios?

Comment: No - each platform uses its own format. You can find iOS specific documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification). The easiest way to get started is to send two notifications, one that targets iOS devices, another that targets Android devices. There are more advanced techniques that allow you to target both simultaneously if you've pre-registered.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and sorry, I cannot test this right now. Is there an official documentation that verifies the answer for the payload in Azure Notification hub?